# Count products that are bought together

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I have made a query that counts how many products are bought together, but I don't want to have the products both ways in it

Code

```
DB::table(DB::raw('tenant_db.sales_data as b'))
            ->selectRaw('a.product_id as product_id, b.product_id as bought_with, count(*) as times_bought_together')
            ->join(DB::raw('tenant_db.sales_data as a'), function ($join){
                $join->on('a.sale_id', '=', 'b.sale_id');
                $join->on('a.product_id', '!=', 'b.product_id');
            })
            ->groupBy('a.product_id', 'b.product_id');
```

Output

```
Product_id          Bought_with         times_bought_together'

52                      24                          3
24                      52                          3
```

So I only want to have it one time not twice, is that possible (based on quantity)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<` rather than `!=`:

```
$join->on('a.product_id', '<', 'b.product_id');
```

Comment: I want to have the most bought product in total on the left side, do you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @BoVerzaal . . . That would be a different question.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.